# choose k from n with a probability

Tags: algorithm, random

I've a list of n elements (e_i). For each i, e_i have a probability p_i to be selected.

I want to write an algorithm to pick k elements from theses n, but I have to respect the probabilities of each element when I choose them. I've no idea how to do that, I didn't know any algorithm which do that :/

Can you direct my reflection?

Comment: [Here is some overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling) (finite discrete distributions). There are simple and not so simple methods all with their own advantages and disadvantages. If that's not homework or for learning, many programming-languages might support this in their lib or a very common library (e.g. [python: random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)).

Comment: Sort elements according to their probabilities and pick first `k` ? Is there more to the problem that I m missing?

Comment: @svasa That would mean your probability of sampling the last element when sampling n-1 is 0. But your approach is somewhat connected to linear-search (cumulative probs, then search). The other algorithms are trying to do it more efficiently, e.g. in constant-time (after some setup).

Comment: Do you want always k distinct values, or would you allow some values to occur more than once in the k selected?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have 3 possible values: `A, B, C` and:
`P(A) = 0.2, P(B) = 0.3, P(C) = 0.5`. Then you will put the cumulative probabilities in an array `p = [0.2, 0.5, 1]`. In each pick you will generate a random number in the range `[0, 1]` (using the built in library of the language you use). Based on that number, you will return as a response the smallest number which is greater or equal to the randomly generated number (actually the class which corresponds to that number A, B or C).

Hint: that class can be obtained in O(logN) time, if the optimal approach is used.

Here is an example:
if you generate value of `0.4`, then you will return `B`, because `0.5` is the smallest number `>= 0.4`. If you generate `0.01` you will return `A`.

That's the idea, I'll let you try implement that. If you need more help, I could write some (pseudo)code too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want `k` *distinct* elements, you could do the following: keep track of the total `remaining` probability of the non-selected elements. Repeatedly (`k` times) pick a random number, `r`, in the range `[0,remaining]`. Scan over the probabilities, accumulating the probabilities until the sum exceeds `r`. Pick the corresponding element. Then -- reduce `remaining` by this probability and then zero the probability of that element so that it won't be picked again.

Here is a Python implementation:

```
from random import random

def choose(probs,k):
    choices = []
    remaining = 1
    p = probs[:] #create a local copy
    for i in range(k):
        r = remaining * random()
        i = 0
        s = p[i]
        while s < r:
            i += 1
            s += p[i]
        choices.append(i)
        remaining -= p[i]
        p[i] = 0 #so won't be chosen again
    return choices

#test:

dist = [0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]

for i in range(10):
    print(choose(dist,4))
```

Typical output:

```
[2, 5, 1, 3]
[1, 0, 6, 4]
[0, 4, 1, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 5, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0, 4]
[1, 2, 0, 4]
[2, 5, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Note how `0` and `1` are frequently chosen but `5` and `6` are comparatively rare.

As an implementation detail: the above algorithm should always work in principle, but it is possible that round-off error and a value of `r` which is extremely close to `remaining` could lead to a subscript out of range error. For some use cases this should be so rare that you need not worry about it, but you could add error-trapping to e.g. pick the element with the last non-zero probability in the cases that the sum of all non-zero probabilities rounds to just below `remaining` and the `r` chosen happens to fall in that narrow gap.

Answer (score 0):

So element ix can be expressed as (e_ix, p_ix), as those are its two components. You apparently already know what values to fill in for all of these. I am going to come up with an example though, so I can show you how to do this without doing it for you:

(A, 1) (B, 2) (C, 3)

What you need to do is assign each value to a range. I'll do it an easy way and just go left to right, starting at zero.

So, we need 1 slot for A, 2 for B, 3 for C. Our possible indices will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

0->A 
1->B 
2->B 
3->C 
4->C 
5->C

This is a basic example, and your weights might be floating point, but it should give you a start.

Edit: Floating point example

(D, 2) (E, .5123) (F, 1)

D < 2  
2 <= E < 2.5123  
2.5123 <= F < 3.5123

Comment: Ouch. You should probably tackle space-complexity here, especially when the input-probabilities are not exact multiples of each other.

Comment: Exact multiples are irrelevant, they have nothing to do with this algorithm. It is made much easier by the fact that you can directly index in this example instead of checking if a number is within a range, but I was just trying to give OP an idea of how weights can be included.

Comment: It will be when using non-integer input. (heavy depende on LCM() of these numbers, ignoring mathematical inaccuracy here in regards to LCM + floats). Your edit is a nice example. Switch 0.5 with 0.35. And now you converted your sketch to a complete new algorithm (cumulative sum + search) / no more bin-mapping (which is actually the alg i propose when someone want's their own implementation).

Comment: You clearly have a more formal understanding of this. I am simply summing numbers over here!

Comment: Ok, I'm slightly frustrated that I posted a very similar response that no one finds helpful. Is there anything in particular wrong with this answer?

Comment: Your's is missing the algorithmics. You did not mention that you accumulated these numbers and why (i'm referring to the FP-example). And more important: what to do with it. (And often one assumes a sum of 1, because the core-element in random-sampling is 0-1 uniform sampling). Additionally, part 1 and part 2 of your answer is not very connected.

Comment: It seems very clear that I am adding some numbers. And I purposely did not use traditional probabilities to show that it does not change the algorithm. The other answer did mention generating a random number, instead of implying it, I'll give it that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Necessary assumption

By linearity of the expectation, it is easy to show that if you pick elements among the `n` elements `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1` such that each element `i` has probability `p_i` of being selected, then the expectation of the number of picked elements is exactly `sum p_i`. This holds no matter the algorithm used to pick the elements.

You are looking for such an algorithm, but with the added constraint that the number of picked elements is always `k`. It follows that a necessary assumption is:

**sum p_i = k**

Fortunately, it turns out that this assumption is also sufficient.

#### Algorithm

Assume now that `sum p_i = k`. The following algorithm will select exactly `k` elements, such that each element `i` in `0,1,...,n-1` has probability `p_i` of being chosen.

```
Compute the cumulative sums:
  c_0 = 0
  c_1 = p_0
  ...
  c_i = p_0 + p_1 + ... + p_(i-1)
  ...
  c_n = k

Pick a number x uniformly at random in [0,1[

For every number y in the list x, 1+x, 2+x, 3+x, ..., k-1+x:
  Choose element i such that c_i <= y < c_(i+1)
```

It is easy to verify that exactly `k` elements are chosen, and that every element `i` has probability `p_i` of being chosen.

#### Reference

The previous algorithm is the subject of a research paper from the 80s or 90s, which I can't put my hands on at this exact moment; I will edit this post with a reference if I can find it again.